# Hast du (mich/mir) nicht gehört?

Tags: word-choice, grammatical-case

When translating "Didn't you hear me?" as in "Hast du mich nicht gehört?" can "mich" and "mir" be used interchangeably? I initially typed the sentence in my translator using the dativ form and it didn't correct me.

Comment: Welcome to German SE. Typically some research effort is expected here, especially since very basic questions will be easily become closed as "can be answered by dictionary".

Comment: It depends on the translator, but in general you can't rely on them to catch grammatical errors.

Comment: @RDBury: you can only expect them to catch grammatical errors if there are indeed errors to catch. With Dativ the phrase would be correct, but meaning something entirely different.

Comment: Does your translator even have functionality to mark incorrect grammar in the input? That's not what they are usually built to do.

Comment: *Mir* and *mich* can be used interchangeable if you want to fake the dialect of Berlin, but not otherwise.

Comment: @RHa: see my answer, "Hast Du mich nicht gehört" and "Hast Du mir nicht gehört" are both legit sentences (everywhere, not only in Berlin), they have just entirely different meanings.

Comment: FWIW, I found [this](https://languagetool.org/spellchecking-german) free on-line grammar checker for German. It does underline "mir" if you type in the dative version, but it marks "Hat mir der Stift nicht gehört?" as correct. (See bakunin's answer.) Note that an underline only means "possible error".

Answer (score 7):

> I initially typed the sentence in my translator using the dativ form and it didn't correct me.

This was perhaps, because there are two *Verben* in German, "hören" and "gehören". "hören" goes with an *Akkusativobjekt* and means "to hear" (somebody/something). "Gehören", on the other hand, has two different meanings: as a *Verb* on its own it means "to belong to" (in the sense of "being property of") and goes with a *Dativobjekt* indeed:

> Ich höre *den Ton*. (I hear the sound).
> Der Stift gehört *mir*. (The pencil belongs to me.)

There is a second meaning when used with a *Partizip Perfekt* (past participle), it is "should be" or "have to":

> Das Fenster gehört *geschlossen*. (The window has to be shut.)

Therefore:

> Hast du mir nicht gehört?

would be quite awkward but grammatically correct meaning "Didn't you belong to me" or "Weren't you my property".

Read more about this and the etymology of "hören/gehören" [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7303/is-it-possible-to-have-confusion-with-different-verbs-that-have-some-forms-in-co).

Just for completeness sake: there is even a third meaning of "gehören" when it is used reflexively:

> Es gehört *sich*, zu grüßen. (It is proper/good manners to greet.)

Comment: If the translator had interpreted "Hast du mir nicht gehört?" as "Didn't you belong to me?" then the translation would have reflected that and the OP would have noted, I suppose?

Comment: If the translator did a sort-of grammar-checking first and thread-O/P didn't wait for the translation itself but only noticed that there is no error flagged, then not. The possibilities are endless and I (like you) don't know what happened, but until proven otherwise I assume good will on behalf of the thread-O/P. This includes believing that the translating device showed *some result* (whatever it was) that puzzled him and he asks for an explanation of this result.

Comment: Carsten, when I used both the accusative and the dativ forms, it was translated in English as "Didn't you hear me?". According to the translator "mir" and "mich" both seem to be interchangeable for that sentence. Neither of them changed the sentences meaning, so I wanted to make sure whether or not that was right.

Comment: @CarstenS Good reasoning, but here's the catch https://german.stackexchange.com/a/76771/56905

Comment: @Dan, correcting input is not the job of these tools. What do you expect them to do on grammatically incorrect input?

Comment: Carsten, usually if you type in something incorrect it would ask "did you mean" and then recommend the correct sentence. For example if I write "I having very little time." which would be grammatically incorrect, it would say in small letters "did you mean .... I have very little time."  It usually offers you something that is more grammatically correct.

Answer (score 2):

Responding to the valid remark by Carsten S

> If the translator had interpreted "Hast du mir nicht gehört?" as "Didn't you belong to me?" then the translation would have reflected that and the OP would have noted, I suppose? –
> [Carsten S
> 20 hours ago](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/76763/very-basic-grammar#comment183350_76764)

Well, I'm afraid Google Translate doesn't aim to give the most correct translation, but rather the most likely/plausible/usable one.

Google just assumed the natural typo in the input, which can be revealed by clicking the translation to inspect it:

[image]

Comment: Btw, I had meant to write "noticed", not "noted".